# ParsleyJS Form Validate encountered unresponsive in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have also same issue mention here
https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/855; 
I have encountering slow, and unresponsive in chrome browser using

```
$('form').parsley().validate();
```

in 800 - 1000 inputs. I have already upgrade to version 2.62. I am the only one encountering these? If these are not normal I will just move in grouping validation instead of form validation.

Sorry for my bad explanation. :)

Thank you

Comment: Hey, so what did you end up doing to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

'@The Whiz of Oz',

I have had this problem as well, and this is how I am solving it.  First, I am following the example of the multi-step form from the parsley.js documentation examples ([Multi-Step Form](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/multisteps.html)).

The change I have had to make is rather than have 1 form element that contains all the steps, I have had to create several (one for each step) which contains the inputs for that section.

Each section looked like this:

```
      <div class="form-section">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" required="" type="email">
      </div>
```

Now looks like this:

```
      <div class="form-section">
        <form>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="email" required="" type="email">
        </form>
      </div>
```

Also, at least for my purposes, the parsley.js validation groups becomes irrelevant and I have adjusted the click event attached to the next button from:

```
      $('.form-navigation .next').click(function() {
        $('.demo-form').parsley().whenValidate({
          group: 'block-' + curIndex()
        }).done(function() {
          navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
        });
      });
```

to this:

```
      $('.form-navigation .next').click(function() {
        $sections
          .eq(curIndex())
          .find('form')
          .parsley()
          .whenValidate()
          .done(function() {
            navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
          });
      });
```

<sub>P.S. `$sections` is a variable declared in the example which is an array of jquery objects of all the div.form-section elements</sub>

The caveat to all of this is now I have to write a more complex form submission function to programmatically collect the data from all of the forms to submit to my REST-API backend via ajax.

Anyway, just my approach, but seems to have solved the browser thread-blocking issues greatly.